# Android WiFi MAC asdress on MIMO devices (802.11ac)

Tags: android, wifi, mac-address

To further prove that MAC address is not good as device Id (see [Get MAC Address of android device without Wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191832/get-mac-address-of-android-device-without-wifi)), I'd like to check if those Android devices with two antennas (MIMO) have two MAC addresses?

That should be with [802.11ac](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac) devices like Samsung Galaxy S5 (I don't have such devices)

Related to [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id) , 
[How to Identify that my Android device Supports MIMO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400385/how-to-identify-that-my-android-device-supports-mimo)

In other words, I would like to try snippet below on such devices.

```
public static String getMacAddress() {
    if (context == null)
        return null;
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService("wifi");
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (wifiInfo == null) 
        return null;
    return wifiInfo.getMacAddress();
}
```